# jquery click counter per day

Tags: jquery, cookies

i have a button that is opening search form in modal (#search-modal) but i would like to only allow the visitor to do 3 searches per day. if he clicks on button 4th time, different modal should come up that notifies him that he cant use the search for that day.

this is what i did so far:

```
  var count = 3,
  $btn = $('form button');

  $btn.click(function(){
      count--;
      if(count<0) {
            $('#search-blocked').appendTo("body").modal('show');                
      }
      else {
            $('#search-modal').appendTo("body").modal('show');                
      }      
  });
```

and it works great, but, once you refresh the page, of course, the counter gets reset. i was wondering can somebody help me with cookie solution that would allow the counter to count clicks per day (i know cookies are not the most ideal solution but for now it will be enough)

thank you!

Comment: You can store its value in local storage, but neither way will provide enough security. Any experienced user can just clear storage and do as many searches as he wants to.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, yes, clearing browser cache would help him do as many searches as he wants, but for now, it will have to work. i am just starting with jquery and dont know much about localstorage, can you help me little more?

Comment: If you want this to be effective then you need a server-side solution. Anything stored client-side can be removed/amended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store its value in local storage.

```
function getCount() {
    var localStorageCount = localStorage.getItem("count");

    if (localStorageCount !== null)
        return +localStorageCount;

    return 3; // initial value
}

function setCount(newValue) {
    localStorage.setItem("count", newValue);
}

$btn = $('form button');

$btn.click(function() {
    var count = getCount();

    if (count === 0) {
        $('#search-blocked').appendTo("body").modal('show');
        return;
    }

    // Do all your search things here
    $('#search-modal').appendTo("body").modal('show');                
    setCount(--count);
});
```

I have encapsulated the logic of count getter / setter into functions so that you can change this logic or switch to session storage / cookie / etc.

JSFiddle [demo is available](https://jsfiddle.net/9e4rs6vb/1/).

With this solution `count` value is stored in user's local storage and lives after you close / refresh page.
Read more [about local storage at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Note that neither front-end way will provide enough security.
Any experienced user can just clear storage and do as many searches as he wants to.

Comment: thanks a bunch Yeldar! i know that this wont help much, and that it would be better to do it on backend... just one thing, this works, but when i refresh the page, counter is reseted and #search-modal opens again

Comment: @Joskosa I have updated my solution so that it always uses local storage instead of global variable, please check the updated version and let me know if it's not working :)

Comment: i hate to bore you this much but now it keeps opening the search modal all the time (previous solution blocked it after 3 attempts)...

Comment: @Joskosa Oh, it was my fault when local storage equal to 0 was considered to be falsy and it was switching to initial value. Please, check the updated answer. Also, I have updated my answer with working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9e4rs6vb/1/